# How do I send a GIF in a text message with version7.0

Tags: sms

I have a Samsung Galaxy S7 running Android version 7.0
How do I send a GIF in a text?

Comment: Bit of nit-pick maybe, but... you can't actually send GIFs in ordinary SMS/text messages (which is what you've tagged your question with). You need to use MMS (Multimedia Message Service), which most carriers bill separately (and are often relatively expensive). Depending on your messaging client, it will automatically switch to MMS (from SMS) when you select a GIF.

Answer (score 1):

The Gboard will help you at this....
it has the feature of sending GIFs,
but that wont work if your messenger doesn't supports that.....
[Gboard on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin)